# Getting Precise Time on Data Arrival, 2 Differnet PCs

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the precise (or very close) time when i get a certain data.
In this case, Recording data from a Microphone and Data from another PCs Microphone sent over TCP.

Now from my own Microphone it's easy, just write the Date/Time when i get the Data with NAudio, and well, it's done.

However, with the Other PC it's not that easy.

I thought first, well why not just write the time it arrives?

Well sadly that's not precise, you would have to know the lag between the data arrival and sending to know that.

Then i though, can't i just send the Time in the same package as the data over TCP?

And well, while it "works" the time is about 13 seconds different, and i can guarantee that the lag is Not 13 seconds, which makes me conclude our PCs Date/Time are different, which is not that weird as the normal Date is not that precise.

(Yes we live in the same region and all that).

Now, is there some other way to do this?

Current Code:

```
 private void Sending(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                var date = (String)DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-fff");
                var bdate = StringToByteArray(date);

                if (connect && MuteMic.Checked == false && skip == false)
                {
                    SendQueue.Add(bdate);
                    SendQueue.Add((byte[])e.Buffer.Clone());
                }
                if (Record && FileCreated == 0)
                {
                    waveWriterYour = new WaveFileWriter(path + Environment.UserName + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-fff") + ".wav", new WaveFormat(48000, 16, 2));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ":Sending", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

"Send Queue will make the arrangements to send them in another Thread, making it better organized, but nothing important there"

Comment: Synchronization of clocks is an old problem in physics.  You're going to have a problem with it, too.  What if one computer is moving at a velocity that's more than 10% of the speed of light?  Just kidding - you can't even be sure that the clock times of two machines are in synch.

Comment: I know, or well not precisely, but at least that Timers are NEVER in sync, except in extremely controlled situations. But i don't need Totally Precise, Within 10-50ms is okay, which i guess should be possible.  Perhaps i am being optimistic though.

Comment: You may send recieved data back to remote computer. Then remote pc will divide time between initial send and recieving data back by 2, so you will have something that looks like your time lag. Then send this information from remote pc back to your.

Comment: Very true, then i could use that to contradict the difference. However, i am not sure how to do this, i would like to do the entire calculation every package(or data feed so to speak), which means everything must be automated.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would re-evaluate whether you really want "precise time" or what you really need is whether data arrived before or after--in relation to--another node (i.e. a relative ordering of events across nodes).  Synchronizing time across nodes is fraught with problems.

I would at least start by looking at things like [Vector clocks](http://basho.com/why-vector-clocks-are-easy/) and [Lamport timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_timestamps).  What you're really trying to do is maintain consistency in a distributed environment.  This is complex without taking a systematic approach and basing work off existing and tried-and-tested techniques.  Brushing up on distributed consistency would also be well advised.  It's a complex and broad field, but having good knowledge of this topic may well help you in the long run.

Comment: The "Precise Time" i mean is simply to know the time both things happened, according to "My Time".

Meaning, if i get a data at 16:00:00, and he get 16:00:01, that would be 1 sec, and that's the time i want to know.  

If his time is 16:00:01 and actually is 15:53:00 or something cause my time is different, than that calculation is worthless.

Though of course, if i know the precise(or close) difference between our times, i could use that in the calculation to contradict it. Not exactly sure how to do that in it's entirety though.

Comment: In order to do that, you need to be *exactly synchronized*--which is effectively impossible.  I'd question why you'd need *precise time* of each event and not relative time.

Comment: I need it because i am saving/recording the conversation by just writing the data received from my recording device, and from the network.  And the data alone don't speak for itself as the recording is not started at the same time and will be a bit unsync (Depending on the timelag). Luckily our lag is probably extremely low (10-30ms) so it doesn't matter that much, but it's a thing i would like to solve or improve.